# How is Xiaomi2mqtt connected to Aquara hardware device

Tags: node.js, iot, gateway, xiaomi

I've already read the **xiaomi2mqt**t [documentation](https://github.com/svrooij/node-xiaomi2mqtt). What I want to know is that how **xiaomi2mqtt** is connected to the actual hardware device (Aquara) over the Internet? In another world, I don't understand this part of the documentation:

```
//Device list:

{
  "device_id": "Nice name",
  "158d000aaa2888": "Bedroom window",
  "158d000aaa5b35": "Frontdoor",
  "gateways": {
    "gateway_id": "password"
  }
}
```

> "158d000aaa2888", "158d000aaa5b35, "gateway_id", "password"

What are these? Where do they from ? What are they used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gateway connects to a chinese cloud service, but it is pretty undocumented.

Next to that you can enable *local network mode*. This is what is used by the xiaomi2mqtt app. How to enable it, is documented on the wiki, https://github.com/svrooij/node-xiaomi2mqtt/wiki/Network-mode-iOS

It works like this

`Gateway -> Wifi -> Chinese cloud api -> MiHome app`

but the xiaomi2mqtt app uses the following:

`Gateway (with local mode enabled) -> Wifi (multicast messages) -> xiaomi2mqtt (running on device on same network).`

Ps. posting stuff in closed  unrelated issues, doesn't really help...